# Why is Multi-label classification (Binary relevance) is acting up?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

I'm new to multi-label classification using Binary Relevance and having some issues explaining the result:

The result is:
    [[ 0.  0.]
     [ 2.  2.]]

Does it mean that the first case is classified [0,0] and the 2nd is [2,2]? That does not look good at all. Or am I missing something else?

After the gentelmen answers now I'm getting the following error 
because of the y_train label [2**,0,**3,4] because of the zero

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "driver.py", line 22, in <module>
clf_dict[i] = clf.fit(x_train, y_tmp)
File "C:\Users\BaderEX\Anaconda22\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 1154, in fit
self.max_iter, self.tol, self.random_state)
File "C:\Users\BaderEX\Anaconda22\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 885, in _fit_liblinear
" class: %r" % classes_[0])
ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 1
```

Updated code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import *

numer_classes = 5

x_train = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,1],[1,2,0,3]])
y_train = [[0],[1,0,3],[2,0,3,4]]

x_test = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,1],[1,2,0,3]])
y_test = [[0],[1,0,3],[2,0,3,4]]

clf_dict = {}
for i in range(numer_classes):
    y_tmp = []
    for j in range(len(y_train)):
        if i in y_train[j]:
            y_tmp.append(1)
        else:
            y_tmp.append(0)
    clf = LogisticRegression()
    clf_dict[i] = clf.fit(x_train, y_tmp)

prediction_matrix = np.zeros((len(x_test),numer_classes))
for i in range(numer_classes):
    prediction = clf_dict[i].predict(x_test)
    prediction_matrix[:,i] = prediction    

print('Predicted')
print(prediction_matrix)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Binary Relevance you should make indicator classes: 0 or 1 for every label instead. [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml) provides a scikit-compatible implementation of the classifier.

Set:

```
def to_indicator_matrix(y_list):
    y_train_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(len(y_list), max(map(len, y_list))+1), dtype='i8')
    for i, y in enumerate(y_list):
        y_train_matrix[i][y] = 1
    return y_train_matrix
```

Given your y_train and y_test, run:

```
y_train = to_indicator_matrix(y_train)
y_test =  to_indicator_matrix(y_test)
```

Your y_train is now:

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

This should fix your problem. It is more comfortable to use the scikit-multilearn BinaryRelevance then your own code though. Try it out!

Run

```
pip install scikit-multilearn
```

And then try

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import sklearn.metrics

# assume data is loaded using
# and is available in X_train/X_test, y_train/y_test

# initialize Binary Relevance multi-label classifier
# with gaussian naive bayes base classifier
classifier = BinaryRelevance(LogisticRegression(C=40,class_weight='balanced'), require_dense)

# train
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)

# measure
print(sklearn.metrics.hamming_loss(y_test, predictions))
```

Comment: Thank you Nedakh. I tried skmultilearn but I got a problem when I add an extra label. For example label [0,1] -> [0,1,2] I got an error TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)

Comment: skmultilearn also expects binary indicator matrices on input that's why it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I think you made a mistake in the implementation. For binary relevance, we need a separate classifier for each of the labels. There are three labels, thus there should be 3 classifiers. Each classifier will tell weather the instance belongs to a class or not. For example, the classifier corresponds to class 1 (clf[1]) will only tell weather the instance belongs to class 1 or not.

Thus, if you want to manually implement binary relevance, in the loop that creates the classifiers, the label should be binarized:

```
for i in range(numer_classes):
    y_tmp = []
    for j in range(len(y_train)):
        if i in y_train[j]:
            y_tmp.append(1)
        else:
            y_tmp.append(0)
    clf = LogisticRegression()
    clf_dict[i] = clf.fit(x_train, y_tmp)
```

However, if you use sklearn, things are much more convenient:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
y_train_binarized = binarizer.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test_binarized = binarizer.fit_transform(y_test)
cls = OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=LogisticRegression())
cls.fit(x_train,y_train_binarized)
y_predict = cls.predict(x_test)
```

The results are something like:
[[1 0 1]
 [0 1 1]]
which means the first case is predicted as: [0,2] and the second case is predicted as [1,2]

Comment: Thank you Quan Tran. I wanted to use my own implementation as I have to add extra optimization to it. Since we are binarizing the labels, do I need to covert it back after prediction to be able to calculate the accuracy?

Comment: I updated the code with a case that causing an error. I appreciate your help

Comment: Hi, the error means that after binarized, one classifier (clf[0]) has to train with a dataset that has only one class: 1. This is because the original class [0] is applicable to all training instances. If you change y_train = [[1],[1,0,3],[2,0,3,4]], things will return to normal. To solve this, you can create a dummy classifier that always predict majority class when the data contains only one type of label. For evaluations, you can take a look at sklearn documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html